# Linux always mount USB device at same point?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have a character USB card reader device and I want it always mount at the same location. Currently its located here:

ls -sla /dev/bus/usb/003/007
0 crw-rw-r-- 1 eveusb root 189, 262 Th10 29 14:56 /dev/bus/usb/003/007

And because I am planning to access from Kubenetes service I need for that mount point to stay the same on all the nodes that have a card reader. So I would like to predesignate the mount point if possible. Can this be done?

Comment: Investigate udev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use udev, little examples are below

```
$ udevinfo -a -p /sys/block/sdc/ | grep model
    ATTRS{model}=="Ext HDD XXX    "
```

Now, that we have model attribute, we can add it to /etc/udev/rules.d/custom.rules by following line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="Ext HDD XX    ", SYMLINK+="<name of device file to be mounted in>"

$ /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

Comment: lsusb yields:Bus 003 Device 005: ID 076b:waef OmniKey AG

Comment: And there is a path:ls /dev/bus/usb/003/005

Comment: but $ udevadm info -a -p /dev/bus/usb/003/005
syspath not found

Comment: Never mind. I found it. Now using: udevadm info -q all -n /dev/bus/usb/003/005